# Training QnA Maker with API v4.0

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I used to use the preview version of QnA Maker and with it the v3.0 API had this train endpoint which could be used to reinforce a correct answer:

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/597045078eb8131608e2f7a6

Now I'm migrating to QnA Maker GA and it uses the v4.0 API. I cannot find the train endpoint anywhere in the documentation of the v4.0 APi. Does the train endpoint still exist in the v4.0 API?

Comment: Good question, I created an issue on Github's project: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/106

Comment: Thanks for that! Will try to follow the issue and update this thread as things progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official reply has been made on Github issue by Prashant Choudhari from Microsoft:

> We do not have the train API in V4. We are re-thinking this feature
>   and will re-enable an advanced version in a future release.

See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/106